# why could windows file affect some awk functions but others not

Tags: awk

I have a file as below

```
cat foo.txt
N N
N N
N N
N N
I-MB I-MB
```

I want to output those lines which 1st column is not equal 2nd column, so I use awk to implement it

```
cat foo.txt | awk '$1 != $2'
N N
N N
N N
```

but very strangely it does not work.

The reason is that it is generated by windows

```
file foo.txt
foo.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

After converting it to unix form it works.

```
sed -e 's/^M$//' foo.txt > foo2.txt
file foo2.txt
foo2.txt: ASCII text
```

So why `CRLF` could affect some awk functions but other not? e.g.

```
head foo.txt | awk '$1 !~ /N/'
I-MB I-MB

I-MB I-MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All awk functions are completely unaffected, they're working exactly as designed. The point you're missing is that when your input line is (CR=`\r` and LF=`\n`):

```
N N\r\n
```

and your RS value is the UNIX default `\n`, the `$0` string being processed within awk is:

```
N N\r
```

so $2 (`N\r`) is simply not equal to $1 (`N`).

If you set `RS="\r\n"` (gawk-only for multi-char RS) then `$0` would be:

```
N N
```

and then obviously $2 is equal to $1 but the usual advice is to just run dos2unix or similar on your input file before running any UNIX tools on it.